# Cannot compile static library of libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, static-libraries, libcurl

I've been reading all over the internet and tried many things but still I cannot seem to find the problem. I'm trying to use libcurl as a static lib but here is what my compiler says :

**1>libcurl.lib(cookie.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fgets
1>libcurl.lib(netrc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fgets
1>libcurl.lib(cookie.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fputs
1>libcurl.lib(ftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libcurl.lib(rtsp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libcurl.lib(socks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libcurl.lib(http_proxy.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf**

And so on..

I have added **CURL_STATICLIB** to preprocessor and even linked with these libraries: **libcurl.lib openssl.lib, libssh2.lib, zlib.lib, wsock32.lib, wldap32.lib, ws2_32.lib** but none of this worked.

I really would like to use it as a static library (without the .dll in the program folder) so I will appreciate if someone could help me!

PS. I am using VS2015

Comment: Hopefully you mean `CURL_STATICLIB` and not `CRUL_STATICLIB`.

Comment: yeah that was a mistype.

Answer (score 5):

Set RTLIBCFG=static in the Visual Studio command prompt. This will set up the compiler to build for  /MT and /MTd . That was the problem apperantly.. Hopefully someone with the same problem will benefit out of this! Cheers!